# What's the difference between "get to here" and "get here"?

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence

> "First you'll need the truck to get it **to here** from wherever you got it".

Is it still right if I delete the "to" before "here"?

Can anyone tell me the difference between "get to here" and "get here"? Are they all right in grammar?

Answer (score 1):

It's a sentence-construction style I think. Both mean same though. The person who found the truck should take it at some particular place (here).

Examples I found:

> *They highlight New England’s changing and complex energy environment caused by a glut of American natural gas and a shortage of ways **to get it to here...*** - [*The Telegraph*](http://www.nashuatelegraph.com/news/statenewengland/1046420-469/huge-expansion-of-natural-gas-pipeline-proposed.html)

And...

> *"It took them two hours to off-load it from the plane **to get it to here,"** said Evans."* -[*The Denver Channel*](http://www.thedenverchannel.com/news/local-news/delayed-luggage-issues-continue-for-united-airlines-passengers-at-dia01052014)

[The latter one is the statement though].

Answer (score 1):

Normally:

> First you'll need the truck to **get it to here** from wherever you got it.

is fine, point A to point B. But if you say:

> I need it right now, so **get it here** as fast as you can.

Using *get it here* is more like a command due to a sense of urgency.